# tksnack- Trying to create waveform

Tags: python, audio, tkinter, waveform

I am trying to use tksnack to create a waveform that moves in real time to the sound being played. I found some example code that more or less does what I want.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
from tkSnack import *

root = Tkinter.Tk()
initializeSnack(root)
snd = Sound()
def start():
    snd.record()

c = SnackCanvas(height=500, width=1920, bg='white')
c.pack()
c.create_waveform(1,1,sound=snd,width=1920,height=500,pixelspersec=500)

start()
root.mainloop()
```

However this example takes in audio from the microphone but I want to just give it an mp3. How would I go about doing this? I tried substituting snd.read(file)  for snd.record() but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the package snackogg...the tksnack works in Linux with the libsnack-alsa fine. I dont know with snackogg.

Here in example with record a track - I put buttons to youre source.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

    from Tkinter import *
    from tkSnack import *

    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("650x560+100+80")
    initializeSnack(root)
    snd = Sound()

    def start():
        snd.record()

    def stop():
        snd.stop()

    def play():
        snd.play()

    def save():
        file = root.tk.call('eval', 'snack::getSaveFile')
        snd.write(file)


    c = SnackCanvas(height=500, width=820, bg='white')
    c.pack()

    c.create_waveform(1,1,sound=snd,width=1920,height=500,pixelspersec=500)

    record=Button(root,width=50,height=50,fg='red', bitmap='snackRecord',command=start).place(x=5,y=501) 
    stop=Button(root,width=50,height=50,fg='black', bitmap='snackStop',command=stop).place(x=60,y=501) 
    play=Button(root,width=50,height=50,fg='black', bitmap='snackPlay', command=play).place(x=115,y=501) 
    save=Button(root,width=5,height=3,fg='black', text='Save', command=save).place(x=170,y=501) 
    root.mainloop()
```